# Amazon route 53 ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

I've just transferred my domain to Route 53 successfully, and have some issues around resolving my name.

After the transfer, I can't remember if I created it or if it was created automatically, but I clicked on the new hosted zone. 
This hosted zone had 2 record types, NS and SOA. The NS has 4 values and the SOA, 1.

I added a record set type A with a name xxx.com, routing policy Simple and set the Alias to my Elastic Beanstalk.
I created a new record set type A with a name www.xxx.com, routing policy Simple and set the Alias to my Elastic Beanstalk.

After a few hours, I typed in www.xxx.com and got a `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`.

I read somewhere to perform a dig operation. I was told the authority section should have more than value, but mine only has one.

```
dig xxx.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> xxx.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 30666
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;xxx.com.       IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
com.            900 IN  SOA a.gtld-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 1451983556 1800 900 604800 86400

;; Query time: 60 msec
;; SERVER: 80.58.61.250#53(80.58.61.250)
;; WHEN: Tue Jan  5 09:46:13 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 113
```

Is there a step I'm missing somewhere?

UPDATE**

I stumbled across the following infomation:

> - Before the Domain Name System will start to route queries for this domain to Route 53 name servers, you must update the name server
>     records either with the current DNS service or with the registrar for
>     the domain, as applicable. For more information, click the ? icon
>     above.

Where is my name server? I originally registered my domain with GoDaddy and then migrated over to Amazon Route 53. Should that information have been given to me by GoDaddy? I've searched my email's and logged onto GoDaddy, but I can't find anything related to a 'name server'.

**Update**

I was going back over the documentation found here
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/MigratingDNS.html#Step_UpdateRegistrar

And I've got as far as

> Using the method provided by the registrar for the domain, replace the
>   name servers in the registrar's NS records with the four Amazon Route
>   53 name servers that were returned when you submitted the
>   GetHostedZone request in the previous step.

Is Amazon not my new registrar?

I got this email from them stating that they are my new registrar:

```
We have finished transferring your domain registration for the domain xxx.com from your previous registrar to Amazon Route 53.
```

Sorry for the long question but i'm not familiar with this process and it just seems like it's very complicated.

**Answer**

Ok, so Amazon was my NameServer:

> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/domain-name-servers-glue-records.html

Once I updated that, everything worked.

Comment: When DNS records are hosted at AWS Route 53 and you are not sure where to start troubleshooting - you can start with checking the NS records of a domain: https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#NS/t.co. Then Whois: http://whois.domaintools.com/t.co (the output also contains "Name Server:" lines). Both outputs should list 4 DNS servers associated with Route 53 hosted zone, they appear in a zone as NS record. If this isn't the case (which happens frequently) it means the registrar needs to be updated with zone's 4 DNS servers. In this case, yes, Route 53 is your new registrar.